# get "Accuracy (average)" from confusion Matrix in R

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I have the following confusion Matrix:

```
confusionMatrix(test_gbm)

Cross-Validated (60 fold) Confusion Matrix 

(entries are percentual average cell counts across resamples)

Prediction    A    B    C    D    E
Reference A 28.0  0.6  0.0  0.0  0.0
          B  0.3 18.3  0.6  0.1  0.2
          C  0.1  0.5 16.6  0.5  0.2
          D  0.0  0.0  0.2 15.7  0.2
          E  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.1 17.8

      Accuracy (average) : 0.9635
```

I would like to programmatically extract out the Accuracy.

Here is the str data

```
List of 4
 $ table: table [1:5, 1:5] 27.9941 0.2905 0.1019 0.0408 0.0102 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ Prediction: chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
  .. ..$ Reference : chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
 $ norm : chr "overall"
 $ B    : int 60
 $ text : chr "Cross-Validated (60 fold) Confusion Matrix"
  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "confusionMatrix.train" "confusionMatrix.train.formula"
```

I cant seem to figure out where this is stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the accuracy isn't stored in the `confusionMatrix` object, but appears to be calculated on the fly from the confusion matrix itself. Nevertheless, you can also calculate the accuracy yourself, because it is just the sum of the diagonal elements of the confusion matrix.

Assume you store the confusion matrix in an object called `cm`. Then the accuracy is:

```
sum(diag(cm$table))/100
```

Or, without storing the confusion matrix object:

```
sum(diag(confusionMatrix(test_gbm)$table))/100
```